# replace algorithm c++ invalid operands to binary expression

Tags: c++, algorithm, replace

I am so confused about the error:

> error:invalid operands to binary expression ('Record' and 'const Record')

I am unable to understand why my code:

```
replace(phoneBook.begin(),phoneBook.end(),old_r,new_r)
```

will get the error.
What means by const Record?

```
using namespace std;
class Record{
     public:
          string name;
          int number;
};
int main(){


     vector <Record> phoneBook;
     string command;
     while ( cin >> command) {

          if( command == "Update"){ // Handle the Update command
                Record new_r;
                Record old_r;
                int number;
                cin>>new_r.name>>new_r.number;
                vector<Record>::iterator itr;
               for(itr=phoneBook.begin();itr!=phoneBook.end();itr++){
                    if((*itr).name==new_r.name){
                        old_r.number=(*itr).number;
                        old_r.name=(*itr).name;
                    }
               }

                replace(phoneBook.begin(),phoneBook.end(),old_r, new_r);


          }

     }

}
```

Comment: Code is missing the includes of  <vector>, <string>, <iostream>, <algorithm> to actually reproduce anything. And then you'll see, the actual error is: "error: no match for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘Record’ and ‘const Record’)"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give Record a operator `==` and it'll compile. Something like:

```
class Record{
     public:
      string name;
      int number;
      bool operator==(const Record& rhs){
          if ((this->name==rhs.name) and (this->number==rhs.number))
              return true;
          return false;
      }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to override the `==` operator in your Record class, because std::replace uses it to see whether your elements are equal.

Answer (score 0):

The templated `std::replace` function needs to check each element if it is equal to `old_r` to decide if it has to be replaced with `new_r`. This comparison is made using the `operator==`. Since you did not write such operator, the compiler is not happy.

add the `operator==` to tour `Record` class:

```
class Record {
public:
  string name;
  int number;
  bool operator==(const Record& other) { return name == other.name && number == other.number; }
};
```